# JclLastExceptStackListToStrings produces an empty string list

Tags: delphi, jedi-code-library

I've installed JCL into Delphi 2010. In the following code

```
try
  raise Exception.Create('Error Message');
except
  on E: Exception do
  begin
    ResultStatus := JclLastExceptStackListToStrings(sl, True, True, True, True);
  end;
end;
```

Also I have this call in the initialization section:

```
initialization
  JclStartExceptionTracking;
```

ResultStatus is false and sl is empty. I have set options to generate map and .jdbg files. Other functions, like ProcByLevel work fine. Is there something else I need to do to make JclLastExceptStackListToStrings work?

From JclDebug.pas file:

Last modified: $Date:: 2010-09-07 19:43:19 +0200 (mar., 07 sept. 2010)
Revision:      $Rev:: 3331

Comment: It would be good if you came back and said what happened, and accepted the answer that worked!

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the reason. I reinstalled everything (including IDE) and started a new project. So it might have been a number of reasons, but I didn't have time to find what it exactly was.

Comment: I get the same behavior while using XE2. I find that I am 1 exception behind. meaning I get results on the second pass.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
JclStartExceptionTracking;
```

at the very start of your application.

[Edit]You already are. Then I'm currently out of suggestions. [/Edit]

Comment: He's calling it in the initialization section. Would you have him call it earlier, or later? If earlier, how?

Comment: He hadn't mentioned that yet when I posted this answer (check the edit log). I'll update my answer to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

JclStackTrackingOptions := [stStack, stExceptFrame, stRawMode, stAllModules,
                              stStaticModuleList];

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem in Delphi XE 1.

1. open **Project Options** menu
2. open **Delphi Compiler** tree node
3. select **Linking** tree node
4. enable **Debug Information** checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I've been stuck with this problem for a few days. JCL stack tracking was working with my programs and I was able to pinpoint the error location. Somehow it just stopped working.

Then I worked with JCL's demo to see if it is working without any problem. It worked very well. I set all the project options same with the demo and yet my program did not dump stack while the demo was working everytime.

Suddenly I noticed that the only difference between my program and the demo is CPU architecture. Demo is 32 bits and my program is 64 bits.

I compiled the JCL demo as 64 bits and it stopped working too. It is working only with 32 bits code. Not 64 bits.

Unfortunatelly my program needs 6-7 gigabytes of memory and I cannot use the 32 bits mode. I suggest to use Eurekalog since it is working for both architectures.